# How to know if my instance will be terminated in ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a autoscalling in AWS, that basically do:

1. Run a python process `script.py`
2. This script get messages from sqs queue to process

My autoscalling is configured to start/terminate instance based on # of avaliables messages in queue. But sometimes when i processing something in machines and my # of messages, my autoscaling trigger to terminate instances, so i end losting message in the middle of processing.

I starting trying to handler signals but does not seem to be working.

My main goal is:

- If i know that my instance will be terminate soon, i will wait finishing my current processes (i will not get any new message) and them i send a signal "OK" to AWS to shutdown the instance.

Is there anyway to archive this? I'm not using load balancing because i manually get the messages from queue.

Comment: Worst case, if an instance is terminated while processing a message, the message will automatically "reappear" on the queue after a certain period. This allows it to be reprocessed. Only when a message is Deleted will it not reappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use AWS autoscaling lifecycle hooks, they will put your ec2 instance in wait state before terminating it and deliver a message to SNS or cloudwatch that your instance is ready to terminate you can finish your already processed message in the mean time, i found an interesting blog post explaining the use case similar to yours .

[AWS autoscaling lifecycle hooks](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/aws-auto-scaling-lifecycle-hooks-2/)

Comment: I will take a look! Hope that solve my problem! Thanks.

Comment: i believe it will